# Can anyone tell what is below error & how to solve this (File is universal (3 slices) but does not containan armv7s slice)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build

I am trying to debug in device with iOS 6 (iPhone 4) but getting error. below is the complete log of it. can anyone explain this? thanks

```
Ld /Users/xyz/Desktop/app-ebcjtnqmxrkylhalerydbplwewus/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/app normal armv7s
    cd "/Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -arch armv7s -isysroot "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk" -L/Users/folder/Desktop/app-ebcjtnqmxrkylhalerydbplwewus/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine" -F/Users/folder/Desktop/app-ebcjtnqmxrkylhalerydbplwewus/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-F/Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010" -filelist /Users/folder/Desktop/app-ebcjtnqmxrkylhalerydbplwewus/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/app.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework EventKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -framework MapKit -framework CoreData -framework CoreLocation -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework BugSense-iOS -framework CoreGraphics -framework MediaPlayer -framework SystemConfiguration -lz.1.1.3 -lxml2 -weak-lSystem -lsqlite3 -o /Users/folder/Desktop/app-ebcjtnqmxrkylhalerydbplwewus/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/app

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine'
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010/BugSense-iOS.framework/BugSense-iOS for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(null): Directory not found for option '-L/Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine'

(null): File is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/folder/Desktop/4.0 app 1010/BugSense-iOS.framework/BugSense-iOS for architecture armv7s

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: have you tried Clean and then Build.

Comment: i think you have included twitter framework in your project. But your framework is not inside the project. instead it may be in somewhere insiede in your desktop. better delete your fromework from your project and copy again into the project destination folder.

Comment: just force quit your xcode. & restart it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"File is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:" It actually says what the problem is. The BugSense framework wasn't built with armv7s as a supported architecture. The 3 slices mentioned in the error are most likely armv6, armv7 and i386 (Simulator).

When you build an app or a static library you have to set which architectures you want to support, see Build Settings -> Architectures. This relates to the iPhone's processor, iPhone 3G and lower has an ARM6 processor, iPhone 3GS to 4S has ARM7 and now the iPhone5 has ARM7s. Since Xcode 4.5, support for armv6 has dropped and armv7s is added to the Build Settings architectures by default.

So basically, your project supports armv7s while the library you're trying to use doesn't. Either contact the developers of this library and ask to add support for armv7s or if you can build the library yourself, add armv7s to the list of architectures in the build settings and rebuild. Or you could also set "Build active architecture only" for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the third party library 'bugsense' that has not been optimized yet for armv7s (note the 's') used in iPhone 5. You will either need to get an updated bugsense SDK or remove armv7s from the 'architectures' in your projects 'build settings'.